# How can I troubleshoot an error: lib/graphql has no exported mutation - for a mutation I have defined and which appears in graphql.tsx

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do in order to have lib/graphql recognise the mutations I have made.

I have an issue.tsx (which is a form). It imports:

```
import {
  IssueInput,
  useUpdateIssueMutation,
  useAllIssuesQuery,
  useCreateIssueMutation,
  useDeleteIssueMutation,
  Issue as IssueGQLType,
} from "lib/graphql"
```

Other than IssueInput and Issue, I'm getting errors in my terminal that say these queries and mutations are not exported members.

However when I try to load the issue page in local host, I get an error that says:

> error - GraphQLError [Object]: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found
> . It points to the line where Issue is imported.

I made all of these queries and mutations in my resolver as follows:

```
import { Arg, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { Issue } from "./issue.model"
import { IssueService } from "./issue.service"
import { IssueInput } from "./inputs/create.input"
import { Inject, Service } from "typedi"
import { UseAuth } from "../shared/middleware/UseAuth"
import { Role } from "@generated"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => Issue)
export default class IssueResolver {
  @Inject(() => IssueService)
  issueService: IssueService

  @Query(() => [Issue])
  async allIssues() {
    return await this.issueService.getAllIssues()
  }

  @Query(() => [Issue])
  async futureRiskIssues() {
    return await this.issueService.getFutureRiskIssues()
  }

  @Query(() => Issue)
  async issue(@Arg("id") id: string) {
    return await this.issueService.getIssue(id)
  }

  @UseAuth([Role.ADMIN])
  @Mutation(() => Issue)
  async createIssue(@Arg("data") data: IssueInput) {
    return await this.issueService.createIssue(data)
  }

  @UseAuth([Role.ADMIN])
  @Mutation(() => Issue)
  async deleteIssue(@Arg("id") id: string) {
    return await this.issueService.deleteIssue(id)
  }
  @UseAuth([Role.ADMIN])
  @Mutation(() => Issue)
  async updateIssue(@Arg("id") id: string, @Arg("data") data: IssueInput) {
    return await this.issueService.updateIssue(id, data)
  }
}
```

I can also see from my graphql.tsx file, that these functions are recognised as follows:

```
export type Mutation = {
  __typename?: 'Mutation';
  createIssue: Issue;
  createUser: User;
  deleteIssue: Issue;
  destroyAccount: Scalars['Boolean'];
  forgotPassword: Scalars['Boolean'];
  getBulkSignedS3UrlForPut?: Maybe<Array<SignedResponse>>;
  getSignedS3UrlForPut?: Maybe<SignedResponse>;
  login: AuthResponse;
  register: AuthResponse;
  resetPassword: Scalars['Boolean'];
  updateIssue: Issue;
  updateMe: User;
};

export type MutationCreateUserArgs = {
  data: UserCreateInput;
};


export type MutationDeleteIssueArgs = {
  id: Scalars['String'];
};

export type MutationUpdateIssueArgs = {
  data: IssueInput;
  id: Scalars['String'];
};
```

I have run the codegen several times and can't think of anything else to try to force these mutations and queries to be recognised. Can anyone see a way to trouble shoot this?

My codegen.yml has:

```
schema: http://localhost:5555/graphql
documents:
  - "src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
  - "src/lib/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
  - "src/pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
overwrite: true
generates:
  src/lib/graphql.tsx:
    config:
      withMutationFn: false
      addDocBlocks: false
      scalars:
        DateTime: string
    plugins:
      - add:
          content: "/* eslint-disable */"
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
```

When I look at the mutations available on the authentication objects (that are provided with the [boilerplate app][1] that I am trying to use), I can see that there are mutations and queries that are differently represented in the lib/graphql file. I just can't figure out how to force the ones I write to be included in this way:

```
export function useLoginMutation(baseOptions?: Apollo.MutationHookOptions<LoginMutation, LoginMutationVariables>) {
        const options = {...defaultOptions, ...baseOptions}
        return Apollo.useMutation<LoginMutation, LoginMutationVariables>(LoginDocument, options);
      }
```

Instead, I get all of these things, but none of them look like the above and I can't figure out which one to import into my front end form so that I can make an entry in the database. None of them look like the queries or mutations I defined in my resolver

```
export type IssueInput = {
  description: Scalars['String'];
  issueGroup: Scalars['String'];
  title: Scalars['String'];
};

export type IssueListRelationFilter = {
  every?: InputMaybe<IssueWhereInput>;
  none?: InputMaybe<IssueWhereInput>;
  some?: InputMaybe<IssueWhereInput>;
};

export type IssueRelationFilter = {
  is?: InputMaybe<IssueWhereInput>;
  isNot?: InputMaybe<IssueWhereInput>;
};

export type IssueWhereInput = {
  AND?: InputMaybe<Array<IssueWhereInput>>;
  NOT?: InputMaybe<Array<IssueWhereInput>>;
  OR?: InputMaybe<Array<IssueWhereInput>>;
  createdAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilter>;
  description?: InputMaybe<StringFilter>;
  id?: InputMaybe<UuidFilter>;
  issueGroup?: InputMaybe<IssueGroupRelationFilter>;
  issueGroupId?: InputMaybe<UuidFilter>;
  subscribers?: InputMaybe<UserIssueListRelationFilter>;
  title?: InputMaybe<StringFilter>;
  updatedAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilter>;
};

export type IssueWhereUniqueInput = {
  id?: InputMaybe<Scalars['String']>;
};
```

I do have this record in my graphql.tsx file:

```
export type Mutation = {
  __typename?: 'Mutation';
  createIssue: Issue;
  createIssueGroup: IssueGroup;
  createUser: User;
  deleteIssue: Issue;
  deleteIssueGroup: IssueGroup;
  destroyAccount: Scalars['Boolean'];
  forgotPassword: Scalars['Boolean'];
  getBulkSignedS3UrlForPut?: Maybe<Array<SignedResponse>>;
  getSignedS3UrlForPut?: Maybe<SignedResponse>;
  login: AuthResponse;
  register: AuthResponse;
  resetPassword: Scalars['Boolean'];
  updateIssue: Issue;
  updateIssueGroup: IssueGroup;
  updateMe: User;
};
```

but I can't say: createIssueMutation as an import in my issue.tsx where I'm trying to make a form to use to post to the database.
[1]: https://github.com/NoQuarterTeam/boilerplate

In the issue form, I get an error that says:

> "resource": "/.../src/pages/issue.tsx",   "owner": "typescript",
> "code": "2305",     "severity": 8,  "message": "Module '"lib/graphql"'
> has no exported member 'useCreateIssueMutation'.",    "source": "ts",
> "startLineNumber": 7,   "startColumn": 27,  "endLineNumber": 7,
> "endColumn": 54 }]

and the same thing for the query

Comment: What kind of tool are you using to create the graphql.tsx file? It seems generated, mabye GraphQL Codegen?

Comment: yes - codegen for graphql

Comment: As pointed out by the response, it seems like you don't have all the plugins installed and running that you need to generate the hooks. Your output looks like you are only running the "typescript" plugin. Check the comment or the documentation and make sure you have them setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

check your codegen.yml

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
documents: "src/graphql/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

or try something like `@Resolver(Issue)`

Comment: where do I write @Resolver(Issue)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not generating the hooks that you are trying to import.

You can update your `codegen.yml` file to add the generated hooks:

```
schema: http://localhost:5555/graphql
documents:
  - "src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
  - "src/lib/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
  - "src/pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
overwrite: true
generates:
  src/lib/graphql.tsx:
    config:
      withMutationFn: false
      addDocBlocks: false
      scalars:
        DateTime: string
      withHooks: true # <--------------------- this line
    plugins:
      - add:
          content: "/* eslint-disable */"
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
```

Comment: I tried this - I still cant find a way to get my mutations and queries to appear in the lib/graphql file in a form that is acknowledged by by form

Comment: But do they appear?

Comment: only as shown in my post- is that what is supposed to be there?

Comment: and they aren't recognised in the import statement in the issue.tsx where im trying to use them to make a form